# How many divisors does $111...1$ have?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $A=\underbrace{11..1}_{2010}$. How many divisors does $111...1$ have?
>
> **Original problem:** Prove that $τ(A)>50$ (or $τ(A)<50$)

**My work so far:**

- If $\tau(A) -$ the number of divisors of $A$ and $A=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdotp_2^{\alpha_2}\cdot...\cdot p_n^{\alpha_n}$, then $\tau(A)=(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)\cdot...\cdot(\alpha_n+1)$
- If $a=\underbrace{11..1}_{k}$ and $b=\underbrace{11..1}_{l}$ and $l|k$ then $b|a$
- $2010=2\cdot 3\cdot5\cdot67$. Then $\tau(A)\ge 2^4=16$

Comment: 3, 7, 11, 13, 31, 37, 41, 211, 241, 271, 1609, 2011, 2161, 7237, 9091, 161471, 493121, 667321, 2906161  are some of the prime divisors.

Comment: [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+(10%5E(2010)-1)%2F9) finds 18 prime divisors, and one enormous unfactored divisor.

Comment: To determine the number of divisors, it is necessary to know the prime factorization. I am not sure, whether it is known for $R_{2010}$. In FactordDB ( a very powerful database), the number is not completely factored. Look here : http://factordb.com/index.php?query=%2810^2010-1%29%2F9 for the partial factorizaion.

Comment: The number has at least $43$ prime factors and is probably squarefree. So, it has at least $$8,796,093,022,208$$ divisors.

Comment: If $p>3$ is prime, then $p$ divides $\frac{10^{p-1}-1}{9}=\underbrace{11\dots1}_{p-1}$

Comment: Therefore, since $2011$ is prime, $2011$ divides $\underbrace{11\dots1}_{2011-1}$

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Winther: I edited a bit similar problem

Comment: @Roman83 Ok, so you came up with it? The reason I'm asking is that if this was a book / contest problem one expect it to be solvable with fairly normal methods. If you made it up there is no such guarantee. This is useful information to add to the question so that people are aware of it. It seems like the only way to solve it is to numerically factor the two remaining 500 digit numbers in Peter's link above.

Comment: @Winther: Original problem: Prove that $\tau(A)>50$ (or $\tau(A)<50$)

Comment: @Roman83 Hmmm, that might be possible to do (at least it sounds more doable). One needs to prove that the two numbers has less than $11$ factors combined (have no idea how hard this is though). You should edit that in to the question. I doubt the problem as written can be solved: factoring a $500$ digit number is so damn hard that it comes with a [$100.000\$+$ cash prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge).

Comment: @Roman83 Sorry; I though $\tau(A)$ was the number of prime-factors so there is a mistake my comment above: $\tau(A) > 50$ requires only finding $6$ prime-factors which is not hard at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial answer: note that
$$
A = \frac{\overbrace{99\cdots9}^{2010}}{9} = \frac{10^{2010} - 1}{10-1}
$$
that is, $A = \frac{x^{2010} - 1}{x-1}$ with $x = 10$.  You can exploit the many factorizations of $x^n - 1$, since $n$ isn't prime.  For example:
$$
x^{2010} - 1 = (x^{67} - 1)(1 + x^{67} + x^{2\cdot 67} + \cdots x^{29 \cdot 67})
$$
This nicely confirms some of your results so far.